Resource of type 'AWS::OpenSearchService::Domain' with identifier '123' already exists
We have an OpenSearch cluster deployed on production with removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN because we don't want to lose data if the stack is destroyed.
So that works but when I try to redeploy the stack I get this kind of error:

Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::OpenSear
chService::Domain' with identifier 'books-index' already exists.

I know the resource already exists, and that's okay; it's intentional. But now that I want to redeploy my stack again, I want to hook it up to the existing resource again.
Is this possible and all?
And if it is how does that work?

Yes, it is possible, it is cumbersome but you can import existing resources via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

When you say "redeploy", do you mean that you destroyed the stack previously? Because otherwise it would simply keep using the resource on every redeployment.

Yes I mean destroying the stack and then deploy againm

Yup - will have to import every time.

This question is similar to: Import existing AWS resources using CDK. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
